# How to use interactive python(like IDLE) inside nppexec console?

Tags: python, nppexec

After running a script, I would like to give commands in the nppexec console rather than a separate cmd window. So how can I run python in nppexec console? Is it possible?

Comment: [According to this](https://superuser.com/questions/463748/running-python-ruby-interactively-from-within-notepad-nppexec-console), use `python -u -i` to execute in NppExec 'console'.